# UVA 10327 Java Runtime Error

Tags: java, algorithm

I need help with this UVA problem called FlipSort. I used the O(nlogn) approach using inversions and the test cases are good. But I don't know why I'm still receiving a `RuntimeError`. Here is my Java code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.math.*;

class Main {

    static int flips = 0;

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            BigInteger[] numbers = getNumbers(in.readLine());
            String ans = getAns(numbers);
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
    }

    static String getAns(BigInteger[] numbers) {
        flips = 0;
        mergeSort(numbers);
        return "Minimum exchange operations : " + flips;
    }

    static BigInteger[] mergeSort(BigInteger[] numbers) {
        if (numbers.length <= 1) return numbers;
        int n = numbers.length;
        BigInteger[] p1 = mergeSort(subArray(numbers, 0, n/2));
        BigInteger[] p2 = mergeSort(subArray(numbers, n/2, n));
        return merge(p1, p2);
    }

    static BigInteger[] merge(BigInteger[] p1, BigInteger[] p2) {
        BigInteger[] ans = new BigInteger[p1.length+p2.length];
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
        while (i < p1.length || j < p2.length) {
            if (i < p1.length && j < p2.length) {
                if (p1[i].compareTo(p2[j]) <= 0) {
                    ans[k] = p1[i];
                    i++;
                } else {
                    flips++;
                    ans[k] = p2[j];
                    j++;
                }
            } else if (i < p1.length) {
                ans[k] = p1[i];
                i++;
            } else if (j < p2.length) {
                ans[k] = p2[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    static BigInteger[] subArray(BigInteger[] numbers, int start, int end) {
        BigInteger[] ans = new BigInteger[end-start];
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
            ans[i-start] = numbers[i];
        return ans;
    }

    static BigInteger[] getNumbers(String line) {
        String[] vals = line.split(" ");
        BigInteger[] ans = new BigInteger[vals.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ans.length; i++)
            ans[i] = new BigInteger(vals[i]);
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: what is your runtime error?

Comment: Hi!, I'm receiving that error from UVA online judge so I don't have access to more details

Comment: check you code with  the possible inputs, mostly the boundary inputs. the reason could be , you program stop for some specific input. try to find it out

Answer (score 0):

I read the UVA 10327. The instructions indicate that

> *Input will be terminated by EOF.*

I ran your program and here is the output when I typed 'EOF'.

```
3
1 2 3
Minimum exchange operations : 0
EOF

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:296)
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:476)
    at so.UVA10327_FlipSort.getNumbers(UVA10327_FlipSort.java:73)
    at so.UVA10327_FlipSort.main(UVA10327_FlipSort.java:17)
```

UVA judge may provide EOF differently to your program. So I would wrap the main method code with a try-catch and try resubmit the code to UVA judge.

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            BigInteger[] numbers = getNumbers(in.readLine());
            String ans = getAns(numbers);
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        // Exit gracefully...
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```